# UITableView cell with embedded view controller self sizing?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm trying to make a use of embedded view controllers in order to keep my code tidy and only doing a small portion of the functionality. So I've gone the direction of embedding a view controller inside a table view cell, all in code, but I am unable to get the cells to self size based on the content in the view controller, any help would be appreciated?

Here's the relevant code for the table view cell:

```
final class ViewControllerContainedTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    private lazy var contentViewController: UIViewController = {
        let viewController = UIViewController()
        viewController.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return viewController
    }()

    func addContentViewController(parent: UIViewController?) {
        contentViewController.willMove(toParent: parent)
        parent?.addChild(contentViewController)
        contentView.addSubview(contentViewController.view)

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            contentViewController.view.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leadingAnchor),
            contentViewController.view.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.trailingAnchor),
            contentViewController.view.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.topAnchor),
            contentViewController.view.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.bottomAnchor)
            ])

        contentViewController.didMove(toParent: parent)
    }

    func removeContentViewController() {
        contentViewController.willMove(toParent: nil)
        contentViewController.view.removeFromSuperview()
        contentViewController.removeFromParent()
    }

}
```

I call `addContentViewController(parent: UIViewController?)` and `removeContentViewController()` in my data source in `func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)` and `func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didEndDisplaying cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)` respectively.

And here is the relevant code for the view controller (example):

```
final class ContentViewController: UIViewController {

    private let titleLabel: UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.text = "Title"
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return label
    }()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        setupLayout()
    }

    private func setupLayout() {
        view.addSubview(titleLabel)

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            titleLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor),
            titleLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor),
            titleLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor),
            titleLabel.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor)
            ])
    }

}
```

I would expect my cell to self size to fit the Title label, but instead the cell remains 44pt height.

Any help or guidance you can offer? Am I using/embedding the view controller correctly? What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Use view controller in tableview cell to make your code tiny make no sense to me. tableview cell is it self a partition of view, I suggest you to use directly subview to tableview cell instead of viewcontroller as child

Comment: @Prashant thanks for you comment. It's to keep the code tidy, not tiny. I have given a very simplistic example above, I know, but my code is a lot more complicated than just showing a title label in a view ;)

Comment: @Gligor I have used this multiple times so it does indeed work. You will need to pinpoint the issue though. So just to get the obvious out of the way; Do you get any constraint conflict errors? Did you setup table view data source and delegate correctly? Does it work if you add some view like `UILabel` directly?

Comment: What have you done to make the cell itself self-sizing?

Comment: @MaticOblak thanks for your question (and answer below) I have tried your answer and still no luck, I must be missing something really obvious and I know I'll be kicking myself when I find out what it is. I do get a constraint conflict error with the `UITableViewCell` height (this one `"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60000132c870 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Height' UITableViewCellContentView:0x7f8f9c21ce80.height == 44   (active)>"`) I don't know why this height of 44 is active when I set the row height to `tableView.rowHeight = UITableView.automaticDimension` any insights?

Comment: @nayem I currently have a cell with a vertical stack view and a label inside it, but I will add some more elements to the stack view and am hoping the cell to just adjust its bounds.

Answer (score 3):

So I have tried your example and edited it a bit for have view controllers work. Your setup seems to work correctly.

Following is a full code you can paste into a new project "ViewController.swift". A table view is added in storyboard and data source with delegate is set.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet private var tableView: UITableView?

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 100
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = ViewControllerContainedTableViewCell()
        cell.parentViewController = self
        cell.setContentViewController(controller: {
            let controller = ContentViewController()
            controller.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            if indexPath.row%2 == 0 {
                controller.text = "Some fairly long text to get a bit of a feeling as to what is going on here"
                controller.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.black.withAlphaComponent(0.2)
            } else {
                controller.text = "Some fairly long text to get a bit of a feeling as to what is going on here Some fairly long text to get a bit of a feeling as to what is going on here Some fairly long text to get a bit of a feeling as to what is going on here Some fairly long text to get a bit of a feeling as to what is going on here"
            }
            return controller
        }())
        return cell
    }

}

final class ViewControllerContainedTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    var parentViewController: UIViewController?
    var childViewController: UIViewController?


    func setContentViewController(controller: UIViewController?) {
        guard let parentViewController = parentViewController else {
            print("No parent controller set!")
            return
        }

        removeContentViewController()
        childViewController = controller

        if let controller = controller {
            controller.willMove(toParent: parentViewController)
            parentViewController.addChild(controller)
            contentView.addSubview(controller.view)

            NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
                controller.view.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leadingAnchor),
                controller.view.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.trailingAnchor),
                controller.view.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.topAnchor),
                controller.view.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.bottomAnchor)
                ])

            controller.didMove(toParent: parentViewController)
        }


    }

    func removeContentViewController() {
        guard let childViewController = childViewController else { return }
        childViewController.willMove(toParent: nil)
        childViewController.view.removeFromSuperview()
        childViewController.removeFromParent()
    }

}

final class ContentViewController: UIViewController {

    private let titleLabel: UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.numberOfLines = 0
        label.text = "Title"
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return label
    }()

    var text: String? {
        didSet {
            titleLabel.text = text
        }
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        setupLayout()
        titleLabel.text = self.text
    }

    private func setupLayout() {
        view.addSubview(titleLabel)

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            titleLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor),
            titleLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor),
            titleLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor),
            titleLabel.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor)
            ])
    }

}
```

This is the result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for trying this @Matic, the reason it works might be cause you are creating a new view controller each time in `func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)`, I'll give that a try and see if it works for me too.

Comment: Sadly this didn't work again. As in my comment to your question above, I still have a constraint conflict with the table view cell height `"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60000132c870 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Height' UITableViewCellContentView:0x7f8f9c21ce80.height == 44   (active)>"`, not sure why and how to remove this one?

Comment: @Gligor Interesting. This height constraint most definitely looks like a potential cause of your issue. The question now is where it comes from. Just to be on the safe side please implement `heightForRowAt` method in delegate and return `Automatic`. Next if this does not fix it try to check if any of the views is programmatically added and needs to disable translation of autoresizing mask into constraints. It could be easiest (just for the test) to disable this feature for all the views recursively. Just to see if it fixes the issue. (Use snippet from next comment).

Comment: `func recursivelyDisableTranslationOfAutoresizingMask(ofView view: UIView) {
        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.subviews.forEach { recursivelyDisableTranslationOfAutoresizingMask(ofView: $0) }
    }`
Call this on each of the content view subviews of the cell after the cell is dequeued in `cellForRow`; `cell.contentView.subviews.forEach { recursivelyDisableTranslationOfAutoresizingMask(ofView: $0) }`

Comment: thanks for all the guidance here mate, I did try returning `automaticDimension` in `heightForRowAt` with no luck again. But I did manage to fix my problem. I used Soroush Khanlou's solution for VCs in cells here -> http://khanlou.com/2015/04/view-controllers-in-cells/ I used the second solution where I hold the view controllers in the parent. Works fairly well, only drawback is having to init all the VCs in the Datasource, but I'm using lazy init so at least it's as optimised as can be, plus I don't have a huge number of child VCs, so it's ok too.